# Python: Can't start Selenium Webdriver (Firefox) via a script, but it works via command line

Tags: php, python, selenium, webdriver

Title says it all. I'm using webdriver on a remote webserver without a GUI. From the command line, I can do this and everything works fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I.e., I can navigate the web, get urls, get source code, and everything else with the browser instance. But trying to execute a script on the server containing the same lines doesn't work. It might be relevant that the script is executed via PHP. Everything in the script works up until `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` - that is, the imports and display stuff all work fine. It's just that last line; for some reason, the browser doesn't want to open when a script tries to do it. This makes no sense and I'm really stumped. Possible reasons/fixes? Maybe something to do with permissions?

EDIT

Just to clarify, I'm doing this all on the remote server. By command line I'm using SSH with PUTTY, and when I try testing the script, I simply do it on the website.

Comment: What is the error?  Do you have Firefox installed on the remote server?

Comment: Funny thing: I looked into it more carefully, and there is no error, it just stops. I have the browser = webdriver.Firefox() line in a try clause, but when it gets to it, it just stops without triggering the except clause. And yes, I have Firefox installed. Like I said, I can use Firefox webdriver fine if I call it from the command line within the server.

Comment: So the script only fails when php executes it?  Running `python script.py` works?  Seems like an issue with php... I'm not familiar with php at all :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by changing the permissions of the folder containing the Python script that called the webdriver from 755 to 757 (i.e., I gave write permissions to all users). I'm not sure whether this was a quirk of my situation because of something else I overlooked or whether there's actual insight to be gained here, but I'd say the take home lesson is if weird stuff is happening when working on an unfamiliar server, check the permissions.